# Simple class to handle Json

Tags: c#, json

I created a simple class which serialises and deserialises Json and C# objects. How is it looking?

JsonHandler:

```
class JsonHandler
{
    public T GetObjFromJson<T>(string filePath)
    {
        T retObj = default(T);

        try
        {
            string jsonStr = string.Empty;
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
                jsonStr = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonStr))
                    retObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }

        return retObj;
    }

    public bool WriteObjAsJson(string filePath, object obj)
    {
        bool successfulWrite = false;

        try
        {
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString);
            File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bytes);
            successfulWrite = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = ex.Message;
        }

        return successfulWrite;
    }
}
```

The main things I'm concerned about is the reading all bytes. I guessed that is the most bulletproof solution? Ideally I'd be using this as part of a PCL in a mobile application (Xamarin) in the near future.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\me\somewhere\textFile.txt";
        var d = new DummyClass("Danny");
        var handler = new JsonHandler();
        bool successfulWrite = handler.WriteObjAsJson(filePath, d);
        Console.WriteLine(successfulWrite);
        DummyClass returnObj = handler.GetObjFromJson<DummyClass>(filePath);
        if (returnObj != null)
            Console.WriteLine($"Name: {returnObj.Name}");
    }
}

class DummyClass
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

    public DummyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

I am only using the `DummyClass` for some quick testing purposes. Not so concerned with the above two classes, and I only included them to show an example of how the `JsonHandler` class will be used.

Comment: [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375(v=vs.110).aspx) will help you get rid of the byte arrays.

Comment: `File.ReadAllBytes` and `File.ReadAllText` could be memory-intensive for large object graphs. Streams are your friends!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some suggestions

- be consistent: `jsonStr` vs. `jsonString`
- be consistent: `GetObjFromJson` vs `WriteObjAsJson` (maybe Read & Write instead)
- use guard clauses instead of nesting
- avoid temporary variables like `successfulWrite` and `retObj`

Based on the suggestions, here is one alternative:

```
static class JsonHandler // class could be static
{
    public static T GetObjFromJson<T>(string filePath)
    {
        // use a guard clause to reduce nesting
        if (File.Exists(filePath)) return default(T);

        try
        {
            var jsonStr = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

            // guard clause again
            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonStr)) return default(T);

            // we could use null coalesing operator ?? here
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonStr) ?? default(T);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do proper exception handling
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    public static bool WriteObjAsJson(string filePath, object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, jsonStr);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // do proper handling
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Also you should think about exception handling.

- if the method returns default(T), maybe reflect that in the method name
- if the method throws on failure, maybe wrap the exception into a custom one
- if the method fails, return `null` to signal that
- use the Try* pattern, look at `bool int.TryParse(string,out int)`

Also, in the `DummyClass` you can use [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) `public string Name { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1):

I find this is not a very useful class. There are three reasons for that:

- it tries to encapsulate `JsonConvert` by another class that does almost exactly the same without adding any value to it
- it hides all exceptions so you won't know what went wrong and
- it does not provide any interface to specify `JsonSerializerSettings` which sooner rather then later you'll need to tune the de/serialization process

---

So what should you do instead? I suggest implementing each file type that you need to de/serialize separately. This means that you should create such classes as:

```
class MySpecialFile
{
    public static MySpecialFile Load(string path) {}

    public void Save(string path) {}
}
```

that may use JSON internally where you can setup the de/serialization process as required by each file. Generic solutions almost never work in such cases.